# UTC DateTime Conversion To US Eastern

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone

I am getting confused about UTC and cannot find anything anywhere.

I have the GMT time of 00:00:00

I want to convert it to the UTC time for US Eastern Standard Time.

I get 04:00:00-04 as the UTC string.

This is my code.

```
string UTCDateTime;
TimeZoneInfo timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("US Eastern Standard Time")
DateTime dateTimeOld = new DateTime(2017,09,11,0,0,0);
DateTime dateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateTimeOld, timeZone);

UTCDateTime = dateTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

var offset = timeZone.GetUtcOffset(dateTime);

UTCDateTime += ((offset < TimeSpan.Zero) ? "-" : "+") + offset.ToString("hh");'
```

So my output will be a UTC string: "2017-09-11 04:00:00-04".

Is that correct? Shouldn't it be "2017-09-11 00:00:00-04"

Comment: Your question is confusing. Do you understand the difference between UTC, GMT and EST? There is a ton of documentation about timezones available, I guarantee it.

Comment: UTC is GMT.  Eastern Standard time is -5 from UTC.  So when UTC is 00:00 EST is 7:00PM (Daylight Savings Time : DST 8:00PM).  It looks like you are converting backwards.  00:00 EDT is 04:00 UTC

Comment: @jdweng So the output should be "2017-09-11 00:00:00-04" where -4 is the timezone.

Comment: @Equalsk Can you point me in the right direction? I am asking, should the UTC string be "2017-09-11 04:00:00-04". or "2017-09-11 00:00:00-04" to be 12:00am local time in EST

Comment: @Sam I think you missing how `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc` works. Since your `dateTimeOld` has `Unspecified` as `Kind` property, this method assumes that it is the standard time of the **source** time zone which is US Eastern Standard Time in our case. Since _this_ timezone behind 4 hours from UTC, when you convert a datetime in this timezone to UTC, the 4 hours will be added after all. Also since your `dateTime` is already `Utc`, your `ToUniversalTime` does _not_ perform any conversation. It would be better to check twice what do you want to do and what your code _really_ do exactly.

Comment: What date are you starting with?  It is -4 for Daylight Time and -5 for Standard Time.

Comment: @jdweng To start with I have the time in GMT. So it is midnight localtime in GMT. And need to get it to UTC for US Eastern. So would that be just 00:00:00-04? (minus 4 for daylight saving).

Comment: You don't have to convert.  The Date will automatically be displayed as a string in local time per your PC settings :             DateTime midnight = DateTime.Parse("9/11/17", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
            Console.WriteLine(midnight.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();

Comment: @jdweng. I am from GMT so my understanding is that for EST in UTC it will just be 00:00:00-04? Is that correct? Nothing needs to be done it it. So the time 00:00:00-04 is actually midnight on EST?

Comment: No, it is just UTC 00:00:00.  Time is store on all PCs in UTC/GMT time as a number.  The Net Library when reading/writing a string DataTime uses the PC Local Timezone setting s to convert to UTC.  So the code I posted parse(reads) Midnight in UTC time.  Then Prints the time as a string so it converts using the PC timezone setting.  So midnight is read, but 8:00PM is displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This use case is much better handled with `DateTimeOffset`.

```
// The source time in UTC
DateTimeOffset utc = new DateTimeOffset(2017, 9, 11, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.Zero);

// The time zone for the Eastern US
TimeZoneInfo timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");

// The converted time in the time zone
DateTimeOffset eastern = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utc, timeZone);

// output in a usable format
Console.WriteLine(eastern.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"));

//=>  2017-09-10 20:00:00 -04:00
```

A few notes:

- GMT and UTC mean the same thing in this context. Saying you have GMT and you want UTC is nonsensical.  If you meant a string in a particular format, then describe the format.  UTC is not a string format.
- The `"US Eastern Standard Time"` entry should only used in certain parts of Indiana.  Most of the US Eastern time zone is represented by the `"Eastern Standard Time"` entry.  If you are interested, see [Time in Indiana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Indiana) for more details.
- Don't assume all time zones will have only hours offset.  Many are also offset by 30 or 45 minutes.  Presenting only hours could lead to data errors if you ever use any of those time zones.
- Avoid calling `ToUniversalTime` unless the source data is indeed in the computer's local time zone.
- Note the output.  Neither your code or your assumption were correct.  Eastern US is four hours *behind* UTC.  Therefore, when it is midnight UTC, it is 20:00 (or 8:00 PM) on the prior day in US Eastern time.

Answer (score 1):

Your dateTimeOld is midnight in EST.

You then convert this to UTC using your timezone and put in dateTime.

Since UTC is 4 hours ahead of EST, this means dateTime is now 04:00 with DateTimeKind.Utc.

You then convert it once more in the assignment to UTCDateTime. But as it already is UTC (from your previous conversion) this does nothing. So it will put 2017-09-11 04:00:00 into the string UTCDateTime.

You then add the timezone offset from your timezone info - which makes no sense.
The timezone is associated with a local time - which is dateTimeOld. By converting to UTC you specifically get rid of the timezone offset.

So either initialize the string from dateTimeOld and add the timezone offset - this would give:
2017-09-11 00:00:00-04

or use the UTC time in dateTime directly with a 'Z' postfix to indicate UTC (Zulu time), so you get
2017-09-11 04:00:00Z

Both of these indicate the same time (unless I copy pasted something wrong) :)

In general when dealing with dates the common convention is to get the data converted to UTC as soon as possible and keep UTC throughout the program - and then convert to local time just as the data is displayed. But you can choose to use DateTimeOffset as well - it can, unlike DateTime, store local time across multiple timezones.